# packer: Error when building from source ova

Tags: vmware, packer, ovf, ova

I am trying to build an `.ova` file using another `.ova` as source:

My configuration is as follows:

```
"builders": [
       {
        "type": "vmware-vmx",
        "source_path": "builds/my-base.ova",
        "vmx_data": {
          "memsize": "8192",
          "numvcpus": "4"
       },
```

(the template validates successfully btw)

I am using:

```
$ vmplayer --version
VMware Player 14.1.2 build-8497320
```

(although I have installed VMWare Workstation Pro in trial mode)

```
$ packer --version
1.2.4
```

When running `packer build` I get the following error:

> ... Build 'vmware-vmx' errored: Cloning is not supported with VMWare
>   Player version 5. Please use VMWare Player version 6, or greater.
>
> ==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
>   --> vmware-vmx: Cloning is not supported with VMWare Player version 5. Please use VMWare Player version 6, or greater.
>
> ==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.

Answer (score 1):

Looking as some past issues on the Packer repo, it looks like the Trial license may cause this error. Example: https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/972#issuecomment-48640599